# How do I programmatically save longitute and latitude?

Tags: 8

I am using the Geofield Map module which depends on the geofield and I want to save lng and lat pragmatically in the geofield via my controller. I have tried the methods below and they didn't work:

```
$WayPointEntity->field_geo_field->setValue("POINT(" .$waypoint['lng']." " .$waypoint['lat'].")");
```

I also tried:

```
$WayPointEntity->field_geo_field = array(
                  'input_format' => GEOFIELD_INPUT_LAT_LON,
                  'geom' => array('lat' => $waypoint['lat'], 'lon' => $waypoint['lng']),
              );


  $WayPointEntity->save();
```

Comment: Any error message ? I just wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50123367/2529954) on stackoverflow, it should help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$point = [
  'lat' => $lat,
  'lon' => $lon,
];
$value = \Drupal::service('geofield.wkt_generator')->WktBuildPoint($point);
$WayPointEntity->field_geo_field->setValue($value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your first attempt failed is because you forgot to add the array square brackets to your setValue:

```
$WayPointEntity->field_geo_field->setValue(["POINT (" .$waypoint['lng']." " .$waypoint['lat'].")"]);
```

Comment: nice and simple.no need for the wkt bs