# Programmatically save coordinates

Tags: 8

I have read in a lot of sources that I should use the `geofield_compute_values()` when trying to programmatically save coordinates in Drupal, but it does not work for me. That function doesn't exist in Drupal 8.5.2.

I've installed the Geofield module using Composer and I can use it as usual in the admin area. There are no problems with saving.

This is the code I tried, which returns an error about a not existing function (`geofield_compute_values()`).

```
$geofield_data = geofield_compute_values(['lat' => $lat, 'lon' => $lon    ], GEOFIELD_INPUT_LAT_LON);
$cbisProduct->set('field_koordinater', $geofield_data);
```

I have also tried this out with no successful result and no errors.

```
$geofield = [
  'geom' => "POINT (" . $lon . " " . $lat . ")",
  'geo_type' => 'point',
  'lat' => $lat,
  'lon' => $lon,
  'left' => $lon,
  'top' => $lat,
  'right' => $lon,
  'bottom' => $lat,
];
$cbisProduct->set('field_koordinater', $geofield);
```

I also tried the solution given in [How to save LNG and LAT progamatically in a geofield](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256857/how-to-save-lng-and-lat-progamatically-in-a-geofield), but it didn't work either.

How can I programmatically save coordinates?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$entity->set('field_geofield_name', [sprintf("'POINT (%s %s)'", $longitude, $latitude)]);
```

Cheers!